# In SQL sort by Alphabets first then by Numbers

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-order-by, h2

In H2 Database when i have applied order by on varchar column Numbers are coming first then Alphabets.  But need to come Alphabets first then Numbers.

I have tried with

```
ORDER BY IF(name RLIKE '^[a-z]', 1, 2), name
```

but getting error like If condition is not available in H2.

My Column Data is Like

```
A
1-A
3
M
2-B

5
B-2
```

it should come like

```
A
B-2
M
1-A
2-B
3
5
```

Comment: What do your values look like? Are they all text only or digit only: 'abC', 'Def', '123', 567'? Or mixed, too: 'abC1', '2Def', '3xy4Z5'? If the latter, how do you want them sorted?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner that column will have numbers and text. it should be based on first character. case insensitive. and first alphabets then numbers.

Comment: Do all numbers have the same width?  E.g. do you have `001ABC`, `055DEF`, or would it be `1ABC` and `55DEF`?

Comment: not its random width max width is 10

Comment: actually that column may have numbers or alphabets or mix of both. any idea please

Comment: You must define the rules how to sort. Shall we just treat '0' as the first letter after 'Z' and '1' the next one? Or do you want to detect numbers, such as 'AB006U' coming after 'AB2M' because 6 > 2? If so, can there be multiple numbers in a string?

Comment: @No Name: You see we are still not clear as to your string formats. Can there be multiple number and letter chunks, such as in 'ab12cd34' and '12ab34cd'? Do the parts have a certain length?

Comment: Your expected output is confusing.  Why doesn't `1-A` come directly under `A`?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: Because 1 is numeric and comes hence after the letters.

Comment: @No Name: Thanks for the example. It's incomplete though. Again: will we have to face situations where '005' is to be considered a mere 5 and must come after '4' hence (in spite of 0 < 4)? You are only showing strings formed of <letter>, <digit>, <letter>-<digit>, <digit>-<letter>. Is this all? Don't you have, say, <digit><digit>-<letter>? Or <digit>-<letter>-<digit>? Are letters and digits always separated by dashes?

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
SELECT MYCOLUMN FROM MYTABLE ORDER BY REGEXP_REPLACE (MYCOLUMN,'(*)(\d)(*)','}\2') , MYCOLUMN
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing can be done is by altering the ASCII in order by clause.

```
    WITH tab
     AS (SELECT 'A' col FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '1-A' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '3' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'M' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '2-B' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '5' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'B-2' FROM DUAL)
  SELECT col
    FROM tab
ORDER BY CASE WHEN SUBSTR (col, 1, 1) < CHR (58) THEN CHR (177) || col ELSE col END;
```

I have Used `CHR(58)` as ASCII value of numbers end at 57. and CHR(177) is used as this is the maximum in the ASCII table.

FYR : [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Given the example dataset, I'm not sure if you need further logic than this- so I'll refrain from making further assumptions:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (myval char(3))
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES
('A'), ('1-A'), ('3'), ('M'), ('2-B'), ('5'), ('B-2')

SELECT myval
FROM @temp
ORDER BY CASE WHEN LEFT(myval, 1) LIKE '[a-Z]'
             THEN 1
             ELSE 2
       END
      ,LEFT(myval, 1)
```

Gives output:

```
myval
A  
B-2
M  
1-A
2-B
3  
5
```